# Set column value based on foreign key table value while INSERTing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables in my SQL server: Flat, Worker, Deal (other tables don't play role here). ***Deal*** table's ***amount*** column value should be based on given ***Flat***'s ***price*** column value and ***Worker***'s ***share*** column value.

I want to perform `INSERT` operation, such as:

```
  insert into KursIsi.dbo.Deal
  values(amount,GETDATE(), 1, null, 2);
```

where 1 is foreign key value for **Flat** table and 2 is foreign key value for **Worker** and I want **amount** value be set to `Flat(price) where ID = 1 + Worker(share) where ID = 2;`

I have no idea how to do it, but I have a guess that it might be related to triggers.

[image]

**Edited**: I added data examples of how I want it to look like.

Here is the Flat table data example. Notice that it has price of 150000
[image]

Here is the Worker table data example. Notice that worker has share of 50000

[image]

This is the end result in Deal table. Notice that amount is 200000 which is calculated as `Flat(price) + Worker(share)` where foreign keys are given in Deal table as values of flat and worker columns. Now it is all done by me, I basically inserted value of 200000, but what I want is automatically set Deal table's amount based on given flat and worker

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! I edited the post and added an example. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply project your calculation from joining the two tables as the input into the INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO Deal 
SELECT 
    F.Price + W.Share, GETDATE(), F.ID, NULL, W.worker_number
FROM 
    Flat F 
    INNER JOIN Worker W ON W.ID = F.ID
```

Comment: The columns on the INNER JOIN were conjured up from your example, however, something seems a bit odd with the relationship you laid out above.

Comment: What if I want to provide a particular ID for Flat and Worker?

Comment: WHERE W.ID = 10 AND F.ID = 11

Comment: Thanks! Highly appreciated. Need this for databases subject course work. Marking as the answer

Comment: Never mind, the whole ID thing makes very little sense to me. If the deal is how you associate the worker to a flat then there is no way you can make the query when no deal exists. I thought there was some quasi association using the ID field.

Comment: The whole idea is flat selling company. So the idea is that the deal is created when the flat is being sold and every deal is made between client and worker, where flat is the one being sold. Most likely my relationships are incorrect, but this is the way I thought would be right, according to my current databases knowledge, which is poor.